# Failed to print json data from the json.txt file in android

Tags: android, json

"brand_name" and "description" these are data in the below json file which i am trying to print on the textviews.Note : JSON data file is under res/raw/brand.txt.

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks inadvance

**Here are my sources**

```
public class Index_page extends TabActivity {

Button white_brand;

TabHost tbh;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index_page);

              t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_des);

      white_brand = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_brand_white);
    white_brand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            get_brands_data();
        }
    });

       protected void get_brands_data() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.brand);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int prdct;
    try {
        prdct = inputStream.read();
        while (prdct != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(prdct);
            prdct = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        // Parse the data into jsonobject to get original data in form of json.

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
        JSONObject jObjectResult = jObject.getJSONObject("Products");

        String br_name = "";
        String br_desc = "";
        System.out.println("------" br_name);
        System.out.println("------" br_desc);
        t1.setText(br_name);
        t2.setText(br_desc);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**JSON DATA**

```
{
"PublicationID": 53,
"PublicationDate": "18/01/2013",
"Publicationbackgroundimage": null,
"Products": [
    {
        "SequenceKey": 1,
        "ProductID": 100630,
        "Brand_Name": "Lindauer",
        "Region": "",
        "Country_of_Origin": "New Zealand",
        "Description": "Lindauer, the country's most popular sparkling wine brand, started life as a bold statement about the quality of wine that can be created in New Zealand's cool-climate. Made from traditional champagne grape varieties, Chardonnay and Pinot Noir and more recently premium Marlborough Sauvignon Blanc grapes, it uses the authentic method of bottling the wine for its second fermentation, a technique that creates the sparkle and distinctive yeasty flavours, regularly outperforming more expensive wines. Wines in this range include Lindauer Brut NV, Lindauer Fraise, Lindauer Rose, Lindauer Sec and Lindauer Sauvignon Blanc."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the problem u r facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do any I/O on the UI thread. You have to call your `get_brands_data();` on a separate thread. you'd like to use AsyncTask.